# Check which axioms for vector space does not hold if we define custom operations

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V = R^2(R)$ and vectors $u=(u_1, u_2)$ and $v=(v_1, v_2)$ belong to V. When we define the addition and scalar multiplication as follows:

$u + v = (u_1, u_2) + (v_1, v_2) = (u_1 + v_1, 0)$

and

$ku = k(u_1, 0)$

Here k belongs to $R$

Then which of the vector space axioms does not hold?

1. $k(u+v) = ku + kv$
2. $1u = u$
3. Closure under scalar multiplication.
4. None of the above

**Here is my approach:**

I believe the answer is option (2), because:

As per the multiplication operation that is defined,

$1u = (u1, 0)$. This may not be true in general.

For some vectors like $(0,0)$ or $(3, 0)$, the unitary law will work.

But for some vectors like $(3, 4)$, the unitary law won't work.

Therefore, the unitary law doesn't holds **in general**.

**My question** Is my approach correct?

Thanks for precious inputs from **@Arturo Magidin**

Comment: Please mention why you downvote and help to improve the question.

Comment: I assume the downvote is because you haven't shown any effort. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Try to show your attempt. Idk why SE user eagerly downvote new comer post, without telling what OP should do to improve post. Now there will be queue of downvote.

Comment: I have added my approach

Comment: More accurately $1u = (1u_1,0) \neq u$ but you have the right idea. Why do you doubt your answer?

Comment: There is no context; there was no effort until the recent edit. Now there is no question present, just the statement of a problem, and your answer. *What* exactly is your question?

Comment: As stated your assertion is false. Since you don't tell us who $u$ is, you have no warrant for asserting that $1u\neq u$. It *could* be equal.

Comment: I have added that u and v are vectors and V is a vector space

Comment: We *know*. That's not the point. For example, say $u$ is the vector $(3,0)$. Is it the case that $1u=u$? **Yes**. What if $u=(0,0)$? Is it the case that $1u=u$? **Yes.** The claim that $1u\neq u$ is *not true in general*; that is, the implicit claim "for every $u\in V$, it is the case that $1u\neq u$" is false. Luckily you do not need to establish such a claim. If you are saying that the axiom, "for all $u\in V$, $1u=u$" is false, then what you need to show is that **there exists** a $u\in V$ such that $1u\neq u$. So you need to *exhibit* such a $u$, **explicitly**, and verify this is the case

Comment: @DeepakAhire could you please clarify why you're asking a question you've already solved?

Comment: @CyclotomicField Is my answer correct?

Comment: @DeepakAhire I am not an oracle, I merely hope to lead you to the solution on your own. If you don't believe your own argument then check the axioms for 1. and 3. as well.

Comment: No, my question is - Is the way in which I have presented the argument is correct?

Comment: @DeepakAhire no. You need to choose a $u = (u_1 , u_2)$ such that $u_2 \neq 0$ first, then your argument is correct. When providing counter examples you don't have to be so general either, you can just say $1(1,1)=(1,0) \neq (1,1)$ and that is enough. One example is sufficient to counter the claim.

Comment: Thanks everyone!